# Understanding interface forwarding with VPN

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling, openvpn

I have a server with static IP address that I rented (Debian on it), and I have a server with a server at home which I bought and setup as home server (with Ubuntu Server).

What I would like to do is: Use my rented server, which has a static IP address I can always reach, to communicate with my home server through SSH.

To so that, I installed and configured a VPN server on my rented server, and a VPN client on my home server.

Everything with VPN looks fine. A `route -n` on the rented server (VPN server computer) gives

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         93.222.111.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
93.222.111.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

where I see that my VPN server has created an interface for my kernel.

**My question is:** After having my connection with VPN server successful, how can I use SSH to connect to my home server?

If I use `ssh user@homeServerHostname` I get an error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname homeServerHostname: Name or service not known

What should I do?

Comment: Does the ssh connection work if you use the IP address instead of a host name?

Comment: @brm Yes, I tested now `ssh user@localhost` and it worked.

Comment: But localhost is not an IP address. I was referring to something like user@x.x.x.x. From what I'm seeing in your post, I'm guessing that 10.8.0.1 is the server's IP, and your home server has 10.8.0.2, is that correct? In that case you'd need to do ssh user@10.8.0.2.

Comment: @brm Honestly I don't understand the structure of those ip-addresses, which I was hoping to understand through the answer of this question. So I don't know what 10.8.0.2 points to. If I try to `ssh` that ip I get a timeout.

Comment: If you type 'ifconfig', you get a list of network devices (eth0, lo, tun0, ...) and info about them, which should include the IP address. For 'lo' (loopback), this would be 127.0.0.1. But we're interested in 'tun0', the tunnel device. Can you look up the IP addresses of debian and ubuntu machines? Should be something like 10.8.0.X. Does the `ssh user@localhost` command work on both servers?

Comment: @brm `ssh user@localhost` works on both servers. The ip address of tun0 on the debian machine (from ifconfig the first two IPs) is: inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2; and in the Ubuntu machine is: inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5 .

Comment: And does `ssh user@10.8.0.6` work, executed on the debian server?

Comment: @brm Yes! It works! Thanks a lot. But now remains the question: why doesn't the hostname work?

Comment: In order for the hostname to work you must configure it in `/etc/hosts` on the VPS. What is the output of `netstat --inet -alnp` on the home server? What is the output of `iptables -L INPUT -nv` on the home server?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I was hoping there's a way to find the hostname without inputting it in /etc/hosts. On the homeserver netstat --inet -alnp gives many connections, but the relevant one is `tcp 0 0 192.168.2.111:49691     93.111.222.123:1194 ESTABLISHED 8339/openvpn`, and iptables command you asked returns:  `pkts bytes target     prot opt in out source destination`

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You could dynamically determine the VPN target IP... But that is not going to change anyway. You should add requested program output via edit to your question, not to a comment. I made a mistake, the `-a` should be left out: `netstat --inet -lnp` And I am not interested in the `openvpn` connection but in where `sshd` is listening. BTW: Using tunnel IPs from the same block as the LAN IPs is not a good idea. I suggest to change the VPN to 192.168.x.y in order to avoid future confusion.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thank you for your help. How is the VPN ip changed? Simply from the config file? And why is tunnel IPs bad? netstat --inet -lnp for ssh is `tcp        0      0 192.168.2.111:22        192.168.2.104:45528     ESTABLISHED 7954/sshd: user`. There are others which differ in port value of foreign IP, but I picked one.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Depends on your configuration. Probably it's the simple case in which both server and client have a configuration file which contains both the local and remote tunnel address. You can easily change that. There should be these lines which need modification: `ifconfig 192.168.116.2 192.168.116.1` and `route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.116.1`. Tunneling is not bad but its main purpose is protection and that is completely useless for SSH connections as they protect themselves.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist `netstat` should not show established connections without `-a`. Maybe you have an alias defined. Try adding `command` to avoid aliasing: `command netstat --inet -lnp`. The relevant output should look like this: `tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:22   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   2107/sshd`

Comment: @HaukeLaging There are many types of the output of netstat, I picked the one with the connection. The one with listen for ssh is `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6844/sshd`. Sorry I'm not experienced at this at all.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I have to admit that I am confused by 10.8.0.1, .2, .5, .6. In general it is useful to give the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` on both systems in the question. But if it works with 10.8.0.6...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thank you. I'll try to play with it a while, and hopefully i'll get it fixed. You guys have done enough :) Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You need a different port on the VPN server, e.g. 23. Connections to that port get forwarded over the VPN by `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A \
   PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6:22
iptables -t nat -A \
   POSTROUTING -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

Forwarding must be allowed on the VPN server for this to work:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Did you read my discussion with brm?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I did. Before I wrote my answer. Do you consider this discussion more helpful than my answer? If so: Why?

Comment: Please don't misunderstand what I said. I'm not saying your answer is less helpful, I'm just making sure you know what works and what doesn't, so that I can continue solving the problem rather than starting a new campaign in some other direction. The discussion made it clear that there's a problem in "mapping" of the hostname on my homeserver. I don't understand the iptables commands you wrote but partially, so should I try to copy/paste them and see whether `ssh user@homeserver` works?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I misunderstood your question. From the beginning of it it is quite clear what needs to be done: What I wrote in my answer. But now it seems to me that (probably just from a lack of understanding) you want a structure that would work but doesn't make any sense at all. You want to `ssh` to the VPS and there you want to start a **second** SSH session which is routed through a tunnel. That is both more complicated (especially with SFTP) and the VPS has to encrypt/decrypt the same data **three** times! There is no need for a VPN if all it shall transport is SSH.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The commands from my answer allow you to (virtually) connect to port 23 on the VPS and be connected to the SSH server at home automatically. This has nothing to do with your hostname problem.